# HTML to PDF conversion using Aspose

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am new to Aspose but I have successfully converted several file formats into PDF's but I am struck with HTML to PDF conversion. I am able to convert a HTML file into a PDF successfully but the CSS part is not rendering into the generated PDF. Any idea on this? I saved www.google.com as my input HTML file. Here is my controller code.

```
using Aspose.Pdf.Generator


Pdf pdf = new Pdf();
pdf.HtmlInfo.CharSet = "UTF-8";
Section section = pdf.Sections.Add();
StreamReader r = File.OpenText(@"Local HTML File Path");
Text text2 = new Aspose.Pdf.Generator.Text(section, r.ReadToEnd());
pdf.HtmlInfo.ExternalResourcesBasePath = "Local HTML File Path";
text2.IsHtmlTagSupported = true;
text2.IsFitToPage = true;
section.Paragraphs.Add(text2);
pdf.Save(@"Generated PDF File Path");
```

Am i missing something? Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My name is Tilal Ahmad and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.

Please use new DOM approach(Aspose.Pdf.Document) for HTML to PDF conversion. In this approach to render external resources(CSS/Images/Fonts) you need to pass resources path to HtmlLoadOptions() method. Please check following documentation links for the purpose.

**Convert HTML to PDF (new DOM)**

```
HtmlLoadOptions options = new HtmlLoadOptions(resourcesPath);
Document pdfDocument = new Document(inputPath, options);
pdfDocument.Save("outputPath");
```

**Convert Webpage to PDF(new DOM)**

```
// Create a request for the URL.
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https:// En.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
// If required by the server, set the credentials.
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
// Time out in miliseconds before the request times out
// Request.Timeout = 100;

// Get the response.
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseFromServer));
HtmlLoadOptions options = new HtmlLoadOptions("https:// En.wikipedia.org/wiki/");


// Load HTML file
Document pdfDocument = new Document(stream, options);

options.PageInfo.IsLandscape = true;
// Save output as PDF format
pdfDocument.Save(outputPath);
```

Comment: Will it convert XHTML to PDF?

Comment: @Mike, Yes new DOM approach supports XHTML to PDF. You need to pass XHTML file instead HTML/HTM. If your file is using some external resources then pass the path to HtmlLoadOptions().

Comment: @TilalAhmad: could you please update your answer. The links are broken.

Comment: @Grevling, Updated.

Comment: @TilalAhmad If I'm generating a PDF of a web page that uses FontAwesome, is there a way to get the glyphs to appear correctly in the PDF? I'm using the above approach but the glyphs just appear as 'unable-to-render'-type boxes.

Comment: @PhilPursglove Please make sure that you use complete source path, where font files are located. In case it does not help, please share the URL of the webpage with us. We will test the scenario in our environment and address it accordingly. My name is Asad and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't get landscape page even though it is set in options and the document?

Comment: @DmytroI. In case setting IsLandscape property is not working, please share your input document with us by uploading it to some public file sharer, e.g. Dropbox, GoogleDrive. We will test the scenario in our environment and address it accordingly. Also please make sure that you test the scenario with latest version i.e Aspose.Pdf for .NET 18.1 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Pdf/), before sharing the file with us.

Comment: Hi Tilal, Thanks, this is a useful answer, however I think I am missing something..My page uses several js and css while rendering..so how can i add multiple htmlLoadOptions? or should i give the root path only? [It didn't work that way :( ]

Comment: @DmytroI. options.PageInfo.IsLandscape = true; should be set before passing it to new Document(stream, options);

Comment: @Samra, we will sort out the problem you are currently facing. Please follow up in respective thread over Aspose Forums.

Comment: @TilalAhmad It is not working with external CSS and SVG elements.

Comment: @TBAG, If you have not reported this problem already, then please create a separate topic over Aspose Forums while sharing all necessary files and details to reproduce this issue. So that we may investigate to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using media attribute in each style tag

```
<style media="print">
```

and then provide the html file to your Aspose.Pdf Generator.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. This is working nice for me

```
var license = new Aspose.Pdf.License();
license.SetLicense("Aspose.Pdf.lic");

var license = new Aspose.Html.License();
license.SetLicense("Aspose.Html.lic");

using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
      var options = new PdfRenderingOptions();
      using (PdfDevice pdfDevice = new PdfDevice(options, memoryStream))
      {
          using (var renderer = new HtmlRenderer())
          {
              using (HTMLDocument htmlDocument = new HTMLDocument(content, ""))
              {
                   renderer.Render(pdfDevice, htmlDocument);
                   //Save memoryStream into output pdf file
              }
           }
       }
 }
```

content is string type which is my html content.